# How can I encode text in ISO 8859-15 on a windows machine?

Tags: windows, microsoft-word

How can I save text with European accents (umlauts, accent grave, etc) in ISO 8859-15 format on a windows machine with MS Office installed.

I need to be able to export these text files to an embedded linux system.

Comment: Don't. Use UTF-8; you _will_ need to put multiple charsets in one file sooner or later...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't have Office/Word, so can't tell if you can specify a very specific encoding when saving a text file, as you can with Mac's TextEdit or Linux's gedit. Windows' Notepad and Wordpad seems to be limited to "ANSI" (Windows-1252), UTF-16 or UTF-8. Therefore....

All of the printable characters in ISO-8859-15 (and the more standard "Latin 1" 8859-1) are in the default Windows-1252 encoding. (The trick is that a few of the characters are in different places.) So any program/editor that will save to a text file should not mangle/lose those particular accented characters. You then need a program to convert to 8859-15.

Linux and Mac have the `iconv` utility built-in. It has also been [ported to Windows](http://www.revindex.com/Articles/tabid/65/EntryID/15/Default.aspx). For example:

```
iconv -f windows-1252 -t iso-8859-15 somefile.txt > converted.txt
```

Comment: +1 and deleted my answer -- this is a much better workaround.

Comment: Yep, Windows-1252 is an extension of ISO-8859-1. When new characters were needed, MS added it to the 0x80-0xA0 range. In contrast, ISO-8859-15 replaced existing characters with new characters.

Answer (score 0):

[EditPad](http://www.editpadlite.com/) may be able to do the ISO conversion you need.